# MySQL returns an error upon trying to push to the database

Tags: node.js, express

So I've been following a tutorial on expressJS and MySQL and I've came to a point where I am supposed to create a web form and then through that web form I push the data entered to the database and then i am supposed to see it on the page that I am redirected to.
This is where the web form is leading to:

```
app.post('/users/new', (req, res)=>{
pool.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?)', req.body, (err, result)=>{
    if(err) throw err;
    res.send(result)
})
```

})
The error that is coming up is the following:

```
code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?)' at line 1",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: 'INSERT INTO users SET ?)'
```

Comment: This is the exact syntax that the tutorial followed and apparently it worked for the people following it, judging by the comments:
Here it is:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/code-your-first-api-with-nodejs-and-express-connect-a-database--cms-31699

Comment: Remove `)` after `?`

Comment: No, unfrtunately it still returns the same mistake

Comment: Then the issue could be in `/users/new` function.  In the body that function needs to return something like this  `users-table-col1=value1,users-table-col2=value2....`

Comment: Are you 100% sure that it does not work with `pool.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', req.body, ...`?

Comment: I just tried it yet again and it still gives me that error

Comment: Hmmm, I've went through the code again and it seems that there is no body parser and that might be the problem

Comment: Yes, adding the body parser solved the problem. Thank you for your time people !